# Docker compose in a docker in docker setup fails to bind secrets

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a project with a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    secrets:
      - mysecretkey
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

secrets:
  mysecretkey:
    file: ../data/thesecretjwtkey.txt
```

I want to automate the deployment using Jenkins. As my Jenkins agent does not have `docker-compose` nor `docker compose` installed, and because I do not want just to curl the `docker-compose` standalone binary to my Jenkins agent I decided to use a docker in docker approach.

What I do in my Jenkins agent:

1. I pull a docker image containing the `docker compose` plugin
2. I clone my project source code inside the docker container
3. I run a python script inside the docker container that creates `data/thesecretjwtkey.txt` and `chmod 777 -R data/`
4. I change the `DOCKET_HOST` in my container environment variables to link the docker socket to the host one
5. run docker compose

The docker runs, the build works, however I keep getting this error:

```
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: MYPATH_IN_DOCKER_CONTAINER/data/thesecretjwtkey.txt
```

However when I go to my docker container `MYPATH_IN_DOCKER_CONTAINER/data/thesecretjwtkey.txt` is here...

**EDIT:**

A simplified version of my `Jenkinsfile`

```
node {
     def image = docker.image('my-custom-image')
     image.inside("--user=root -e DOCKER_HOST=${env.DOCKER_HOST}") {
        stage('clone') { 
           checkout scm
        }
        stage('Deploy') { 
           sh "python3 -u deployscripts/deploy.py"
        }
     }

}
```

In my `deploy.py` I have something like this

```
generate_secret(secret_path="data/thesecretjwtkey.txt")
os.system("docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up build")
```

An overview of my simplified project tree:

```
├── backend
├── data
│   └── thesecretjwtkey.txt
├── deployscripts
│   └── deploy.py
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Jenkinsfile
```

Locally on my machine everything works fine ...

Comment: In cases where you have relative paths, Compose will interpret them relative to the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file, but in your setup that's inside the Compose container's filesystem and not the Docker daemon's filesystem.  Would it be possible to [edit] the question to include the actual Jenkinsfile?

Comment: How can I tell him to fetch the secret from the current file system (the one inside the docker) and not the host ?

Comment: The error message references a bind mount, which doesn't quite match your configuration, but a bind mount will _always_ come from the environment with the Docker daemon, rather than from the environment of the tool calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```bash
 [ Jenkins Agent (Host) ]
   │
   └─ [ Docker Container (DinD Environment) ]
         │
         ├─ [ Cloned Project ]
         │    ├─ backend
         │    ├─ data
         │    │   └─ thesecretjwtkey.txt (Not accessible to Docker Daemon)
         │    ├─ deployscripts
         │    │   └─ deploy.py
         │    └─ docker-compose.yml
         │
         └─ [ Docker Compose ]
               └─ [ Backend Service ]
                   └─ Secret Bind: ../data/thesecretjwtkey.txt (Path interpreted by Docker Daemon)
```

The Docker daemon, running on the Jenkins host, is trying to access `../data/thesecretjwtkey.txt`, but this path is resolved in the host's filesystem, not within the Docker container.
The `thesecretjwtkey.txt` file is actually inside the Docker container, inaccessible to the Docker daemon on the host.

You need to correct the file path in `docker-compose.yml`, to reflect where it is accessible on the Jenkins host, not inside the Docker container.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    # existing configuration 
    secrets:
      - mysecretkey
secrets:
  mysecretkey:
    file: /path/accessible/to/docker/daemon/thesecretjwtkey.txt
```

And configure the Jenkins pipeline to make the secret file available at a path accessible to the Docker daemon on the host: make sure the Jenkins pipeline maps the directory containing `thesecretjwtkey.txt` from the Jenkins agent into the Docker container at a path the Docker daemon can access.

```
node {
    def image = docker.image('my-custom-image')
    image.inside("--user=root -e DOCKER_HOST=${env.DOCKER_HOST} -v /path/on/jenkins/agent:/path/accessible/to/docker/daemon") {
        // existing stages 
    }
}
```